# C# analog for sql in operator

Tags: c#

There is in operator in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Is there similar sintax in C#, I mean

```
if(variable in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)){
}
```

Comment: Actualy the question is, what is the easier way to do such a thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a good one but you can write it yourself as an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] items)
  {
      return items.Contains(value);
  }
}

if (v.In(1,2,3,5)) { /* do stuff */ }
```

I haven't tested it, but it should be good.

UPDATE: As suggested by OP, I've corrected a few typos.

Comment: wow, this is realy cool

I've corrected it a little bit

public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] items) {

            return items.Contains(value);

        }

Answer (score 14):

You can have

```
int[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

if(data.Contains(variable))
{

}
```

Comment: This realy works, but in my humble opinion pblasucci's answer is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or newer then you can use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx):

```
if (new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Contains(variable))
{
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx)

```
new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}.Contains(variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to put together an extension.

```
public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] items) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (value.Equals(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```